# Unobtrusive Validation on en-GB Dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-globalization

I am designing a data input form using asp.net MVC4 which has an input of type date.

Using the unobtrusive jQuery library in chrome and jQueryUI datepicker I was still getting an error (The field news_date must be a date.), after selecting a correct date format, using the datepicker (i.e. 14/02/2013) and submitting the form.

Some [searching](http://blog.brainnovative.com/2010/12/globalizing-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive.html) suggested I should use the jQuery.globilization library. So after reading the [documentation](https://github.com/jquery/globalize#parseDate) I added a reference to the following script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.culture = Globalize.culture("en-GB");
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-GB");
    }
});
```

However I am still getting the error

If I debug the the above code in chrome i can see that the value of "value) is "2014-02-14".

Below is html which gets rendered.

```
<div class="editor-field">

<input class="text-box single-line datepicker hasDatepicker input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field news_date must be a date." id="news_date" name="news_date" type="date" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy" });
    });
    </script>
            <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="news_date" data-valmsg-replace="true"><span for="news_date" class="" style="">The field news_date must be a date.</span></span>
        </div>
```

**UPDATE**: incidentally if i change my validator method to hardcode. 
i.e.

```
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate("14/03/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-GB")
}
```

It works. So it definately appears to be the format that the date is being stored on the page prior to POST or submit validation which is the issue.

**UPDATE**
              after selecting the date if i run `$('#news_date').val()` in the chrome console, i get "2014-02-14" and i can debug my script and see the value being passed it the validator method it is this value and thus it doesnt match the british date format thus returning a null, rather than a value which would pass validation. So is my problem with how the datepicker is storing the date after selection?

Has anyone found a workaround for this in Chrome?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This workaround appears to handle chrome and ie etc. In chrome I cannot type in an incorrect date so the date picker will give me a valid date and when it passes it to the validator function it will be in the yyyy-mm-dd format. i.e lets me type straight into the input or use the picker, typing in an invalid date i.e. 2/30/2013 (invalid in en-GB culture) it correctly invalidates it and prevents further progress. If no better suggestions I think ill go with this as the best workable answer

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.culture = Globalize.culture("en-GB");
$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    //This is not ideal but Chrome passes dates through in ISO1901 format regardless of locale 
    //and despite displaying in the specified format.

    return this.optional(element)
        || Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/mm/yyyy", "en-GB")
        || Globalize.parseDate(value, "yyyy-mm-dd");
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, been banging my head against a wall all day and this worked a charm. Incidentally I couldn't get it to work with latest version of Globalize.js (v1.1.0) since it's all changed to CLDR. Works fine with an older version v0.1.1 though.

Answer (score -1):

*Can i suggest you another work around, Put this in your web.config to avoid issues with differenet culture settings.*

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
```

And in Jquery datepicker this would be enough,

```
 $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy" });
 });
```

Comment: I already have this, with the exception of the two encoding attributes. Changed this and i still get the same. The date picker allows me to pick a date and it looks GB format in the display, but when it passes through to the validator its passing though in the format yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: can you try decorating your controller with [HttpPost] attribute.

Comment: We had a issue like this - http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx

Comment: ssilas777 not sure that suggestion would help as this is all client side validation, its not even passed a GET or POST at this point. I verified using Fiddler.

Comment: Have you tried that, unobtrusive should have ajax in background?

Comment: ssilas777, my controller's form submit method is decorated with [HttpPost] and this does work in ie and ffx its just chrome where it doesnt. I also cannot see any traffic in fiddler to the controller via ajax.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
 });
```