# jQuery date validation MVC 4 .Net 4.5.1 UK date "must be a date" Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, date, jquery-validate, globalization

I have an app that I have recently upgraded to .Net 4.5.1 and MVC 4. I am using the jQuery datepicker and jQuery.validation 1.11.1.

I am in the UK therefore the dates will be in the en-GB locale ("dd/mm/yyyy"). I have tried what is suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053022/mvc-datetime-validation-uk-date-format/14081487#14081487), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427504/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-format-issue-with-initial-value) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147080/unobtrusive-validation-on-en-gb-dates) but to no avail.

I also have in my web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-GB" culture="en-GB" />
```

and have set the globalisation in IIS to en-GB, but every date that is input is validated as a US format date.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I had the same problem a while a ago, couldn't find an apt solution for the issue, as a work around, I disabled the MVC's Client validation, wrote my own custom validation for `required` and set the input date field as `readonly` so users can't modify the date provided using `datepicker`

Comment: When you apply the solution above this problem will occure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26279779/validation-of-datetimepicker-is-not-working-properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the date validation method in jQuery.validate.js to the follwing solved the issue:

```
date: function (value, element) {
        $.culture = Globalize.culture("en-GB");
        var date = Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-GB");
        return this.optional(element) || 
                       !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(date).toString());
    }
```

Tested in Chrome, FF and IE

Comment: In the jQuery.validate.js file in your solution

Comment: And Do i need To add `Globalize.js` because I replaced the Old `date: function ...` with this one but it didn't worked Always I'm getting `The filed ... must be Date`

Comment: Yes I am also facing same problem though I had done as said... Any suggestions?

Comment: I also get error after implementing this that its looking for Globalize.js, not sure what that is or where to put it

Answer (score 0):

in The Jquery which is calling simply add the format.

$(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
});

http://www.matthewcarlin.co.uk/jquery-quick-tip-2-changing-date-format

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.  They are asking to validate the date produced from the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

Having just had to figure this out, I overrode the rule and used a data attribute

```
if (typeof jQuery.validator.methods.date !== 'function') {
    var f = function (value, element) {
        var e = $(element).attr('data-dateformat');
        if (e && (e.length)) {
            var dt = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(e, value);
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(dt.toString());
        } else {
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value).toString());
        }
    }
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("date", f);
} else {
    var m = jQuery.validator.methods.date;
    var f = function(value, element) {
        var e = $(element).attr('data-dateformat');
        if (e && (e.length)) {
            var dt = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate(e, value);
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(dt.toString());
        } else {
            return m(value, element);
        }
    }
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("date", f);
}
```

It ASSUMES you have datepicker, but if you are using dates, and jQuery, I think that's a safe bet.
If the element has a date format defined in data-dateformat it will parse it using that, otherwise it will fall back to the default date rule, and if that wasn't present it implements the default rule.

I placed this in my site global code file to keep it outside the jQuery scripts