# ASP.Net MVC4: The field xxx must be a date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with EditorFor(DateTime) function. I have a model defined like this:

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(MessageSearchDTO_Validation))]
    public class MessageSearchDTO
    {
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class MessageSearchDTO_Validation
    {
        [DisplayName("Od")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.FieldRequired)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Do")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}")]
        [CustomValidation(typeof(MessageSearchDTO_Validation), "EndDate_CustomValidator")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = ErrorMessages.FieldRequired)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I want a full date with time editor. But it works only in Chrome. In FF/IE I'm getting this javascript validation error.
If I set the value of "10/23/2013 12:00:00 AM" it works fine. But how do I force the datetime format I desire?

I even tried to implement custom binder, it didn't work because this is client side error...

Answer (score 6):

I guess [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19519745/2121389) might solve your problem

> Changing the date validation method in jQuery.validate.js to the
>   follwing solved the issue:

```
date: function (value, element) {
         $.culture = Globalize.culture("en-GB");
         var date = Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", "en-GB");
         return this.optional(element) || 
                        !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(date).toString());
     }
```

Modify them based on your requirement

Comment: DO I need to add `Globalize` file or function ?

Comment: This is worked perfect for me. I was facing this issue in Safari browser.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was:

```
    date: function (value, element) {
        if (value.indexOf(' ') != -1)
            value = value.replace(' ', 'T');
        return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
    },
```

I do not like it very much :( Isn't it possible to do it some nice way without modifying jquery???

Answer (score 0):

AthibaN's answer is correct. You need to include globalize.js and globalize.yourRegionHere.js

My solution is to add in layout file after jquery is loaded script tag with

```
  $(function () {
                    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
                     Globalize.culture("bs-Latn-BA");

             return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value)     !== null;
                }
            });
```

This way its less intrusive.

Answer (score -1):

Send ticks ([DateTime.Ticks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx)) instead of datetime string to client side. Then parse ticks to the date format you want with javascript.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966559/how-to-convert-javascript-date-object-into-ticks) can help.

Comment: Send ticks? The question is about client-side validation before send data back to the server.

Comment: I mean if you transfer dates using ticks, you can handle it whatever browser you use. As I understood you are sending dates as string like "10/23/2013 12:00:00 AM", this may not be a generic format between browsers, however ticks is generic. Thank you.