# How to check jQuery Validate default rules?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, cross-browser, unobtrusive-validation

I use **jquery.validate.unobtrusive** library to validate my forms in **ASP.NET MVC** project.   I always have a problems with `Date` validation and `decimal` numbers validation.

I have problems because in defferent cases I should use different localization and every locale have its own `Date` and `decimal` format.

I know that I can add [Globalize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172851/1849444) library to solve this problem once and for all. But in some projects I can't use this library.

How can I check what validation **masks** (or **rules** in general) set up for `Date`, `decimal` and maybe some other locale sensitive types at the moment in different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are located in the `jquery.validate.js` file (towards the end). For example the following are the rules for `date` and `number` in version 1.9.0.

```
// date
return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
// number
return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(value); //
```